# serve application in subfolder instead of root domain

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I deployed my app in example.com/app but all my routes are broken.

Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://example.com/app/."

I can try to manually prepend to all routes /app/ subfolder but it doens't seem the right approach, especially since i use a cms package (orionjs) to generate the /admin interface, which doesn't have support to change the admin path.

Is there any way to prepend the /app folder to all routes by default? 
What i find strange is that i defined ROOT_URL to http://example.com/app/ but iron router seems to ignore it. Did i skip a step ?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many web platforms (ex: php), the folder structure under your app does **not** map automatically to routes. If you're using iron-router you basically define what *layout* maps to what route. The layout can be defined in an HTML file in any folder (except under `/server` or `/public`) at *any depth*. You can also add any extra depth you want to any route in iron-router by prepending `app/` or whatever you want to your route definitions. Your `ROOT_URL` should remain http://example.com/

Comment: To give more context, on the root domain i'm having a ruby on rails app. I settted up with nginx for the subfolder to be a proxy to meteor. What you are saying is that i need to set up `ROOT_URL` to be `example.com` and change the individual routes from iron router to prepend `app/` to them ?

Comment: That makes things more interesting. The better way IMO to do this is to leave both your RoR and Meteor app running on root and just have nginx do the top level routing. i.e. anything going to `/app` is redirected to Meteor with the `/app` removed. See *Step 3* and *Step 7* of https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0 This keeps both apps simple.